# Laravel 5.4 Bootstrap cache force delete

Tags: laravel-5

I have a question. In my case AM 1:00 some-laravel project/bootstrap/cache/services.php was force deleted, but I don't know the reason. Our code doesn't have any call artisan clear cache command, and anyone doesn't call artisan command manually. Does anybody have the same case as my case? If you have the same case as my case and find cause plz comment, my question causes our environment.

1. AWS EC2
2. laravel version : laravel 5.4.33
3. php version : PHP 7.1.4 (cli) (built: Oct 26 2017 15:49:30) ( ZTS )
4. Apache version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
5. OS : CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
6. dependency

```json
{
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "ammadeuss/laravel-html-dom-parser": "^1.0",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.160",
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.3",
    "caouecs/laravel-lang": "~3.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
    "fightbulc/moment": "^1.26",
    "graham-campbell/exceptions": "^9.3",
    "ixudra/curl": "^6.10",
    "laracasts/utilities": "^3.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4",
    "php-imap/php-imap": "^3.0",
    "phpoffice/phpexcel": "^1.8",
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.2",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^2.6",
    "rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer": "^0.10.0",
    "yajra/laravel-oci8": "5.4.*"
}
```

Comment: opps.. file was not delete but bootstrap/cache/services.php file overwrite to empty string sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Run
`php artisan config:cache` to recache the services

Comment: already try this command but console Say "Session Class Is Not Defined"... and i want reason of this case...